# How to set a value to NULL across the whole dataset?

Tags: null, tableau-api

I have a dataset where unknown, missing or otherwise `NULL`-like values are coded as `-9999999`. This is done in Dimensions and Measurement columns.

How can I instruct Tableau to treat `-9999999` as `NULL` in the whole dataset?

I have `.csv`, Excel and `.shp` files, but I'm trying to find out a general way to do this in Tableau.

### Things I have tried

#### Creating a calculated column

I have created a calculated column with:

```
IFF([Column] == -9999999, NULL, [Column])
```

However, this is too tedious to do with all columns.

#### Creating an alias

I have attempted to create aliases, however, this only works for Dimensions not Measures.

#### Exporting as `.csv` and editing

I have exported my dataset as a `.csv` file, then edited in a text-editor (replaced all occurrences of `-9999999` with `NULL`) and re-loaded the data from the `.csv` file. This works, but feels sub-optimal. For example, `.shp` files cannot be exported lossless to a `.csv` file.

Comment: I don't think tableau has any generic data replacement mechanism embeeded, but interested to see responses from experts

Comment: Depending on your data source type, you could use custom SQL when connecting and replace it there. Need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau does not natively have functionality to treat all matching values in a dataset and convert them to NULL. You have a few options.

1. Calculated fields. You tried this and I agree, it can be tedious with many dimensions and measures. Same with aliases, which would be even more cumbersome.
2. Change the output from the source system that generates your data. If it's a database, create a view that does the conversion for you.
3. If you are using a data extract, use the Tableau Extract API and write a wrapper program that will convert the values to null. This could easily be done with loops and hit all the fields at once.
4. If you have an ETL tool such as Informatica or Talend, run the source data through it first to do the data conversion.
5. If it's a file-based datasource, use a program that has automated search-and-replace capabilities. A command-line GREP program or Notepad++ might do the trick.